# RStudio does not engage

Tags: r, rstudio

When I am open RStudio I get:

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/Àíòîí/Documents/.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

And it's stucks with message `Loading workspace from ~/.RData` (I cannot make anything)

How to fix this and change this directory?

Comment: In RStudio: What is => Tools => Global Options => working directory? Perhaps a duplicate of [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432344/how-do-you-change-the-default-directory-in-rstudio-or-r)?

Comment: In the menu `\Tools\Global Options\General` untick the box "Restore .Rdata into workspace at startup"