# How to set working directory pemanently in Spyder & RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, spyder

I have started learning - Machine learning course on Windows OS. Whenever I start a new instance of Spyder 3.2.4(Python 3.6) & RStudio(1.1.383), every time I need to set my current working directory in these IDEs. Is there any way to set them pemanently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432344/how-do-you-change-the-default-directory-in-rstudio-or-r

Comment: @Scarabee, Thanks it helped me to set my RStudio working directory pemanently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To set working directory permanently in:
>   1. Spyder IDE: Tools > Prefeences > Current working directory > the following directory
>   2. RStudio IDE: Tools > Global Options... > General > Default working directory (when not in a project)
>
> PS: Yes, we need to restart the application in both IDEs to take
>   changes in effect.

Answer (score 21):

In Spyder (since version **3.2**) you need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > Current working directory`

and select the option called

`the following directory`

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, but need to restart the application to get the changes in effect.

Comment: You don't need to restart Spyder, but the kernel associated to a console or opening a new console for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

In Spyder whenever you run your script for the first time it will go to current directory automatically. You just have to run for the first time.
Make sure you have selected

Tools > Preferences > Current working directory

Answer (score -3):

For Mac:

Click "python" in top left corner.

Click preferences.

Current working directory.

Boom.