# Altering the path on Spyder

Tags: python, path, spyder

I'm using Python 3.6 with Spyder in an Anaconda installation. I am trying to learn to manipulate the path that Spyder knows. I went to PYTHONPATH manager, and added `/Users/ericauld/Desktop`.

I have a file called `Something.txt` on my desktop, and Spyder will recognize it if I say `'/Users/ericauld/Desktop/Something.txt'`, but not if I write `Something.txt`, even though the path is now supposed to include my desktop.

I tried restarting the kernel, but that didn't change anything.

I'm sure my error is quite elementary. Sorry if this question has already been answered, I haven't found a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PYTHONPATH variable](https://github.com/flatironinstitute/CaImAn/wiki/Setting-up-Python-and-getting-to-know-Spyder#the-pythonpath-variable)

> ...tells Python where to find **installed packages** if they're not
>   installed in the standard (system) places

However it looks like you want to tell Spyder where to look for files your scripts will be using. In this case I can suggest two solutions:

1. [Set your working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47916268/3491991) to the directory where you code and related files should reside.
2. Organize project/files into directories like so

   [image]

Then give your script `analyze_something.py` access to the files it needs like so:

```
import os

#%% Setup paths
script_dir = os.path.abspath('')
project_dir =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(''))
data_dir = os.path.join(project_dir, 'data')

print(script_dir)
# >>  C:\Users\path_to_your_project\Example Project Folder\code
print(project_dir)
# >>   C:\Users\path_to_your_project\Example Project Folder
print(data_dir)
# >>  C:\Users\path_to_your_project\Example Project Folder\data
```

The benefit of the latter option is that it's more organized and more portable.

Finally, checkout using [environments with conda](https://tdhopper.com/blog/my-python-environment-workflow-with-conda/) when you really need portability.