# Set to working directory in Spyder for MacOs

Tags: spyder, filepath

I am a newbie at this so apologies for the banal question but I cannot find an answer anyway. I cannot seem to find a "set to working directory" button in Spyder - I am using it on a Mac with Mojave 10.14 installed. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916268/how-to-set-working-directory-pemanently-in-spyder-rstudio ?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) That was removed several years ago and it's not necessary anymore.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.