# How can I change R home directory?

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio

I need to change the home directory for R / Rstudio, at the moment it works in the OneDrive folder , and it creates problems with sync.
What I would like to change is not just the directory where libraries are installed.
For example, I always get the `.Rhistory` file in the OneDrive directory, as well as the libraries.
I would like "move" everything to another directory.

I tried with `.Renviron` file, but it still needs to be placed inside the OneDrive folder, and still I didn't succeed in have evrything moved in another place.

How can I do it?

Comment: setwd("your_path_goes_here")

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny he does not want to change only the working directory.

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432344/how-do-you-change-the-default-directory-in-rstudio-or-r

Comment: In RStudio, go to Tools, Global Options, and you'll have a window popup. In the General tab, the second line shows what default working directory you want when not in a project. Just click on the Browse button beside it and point to the location you want.

Comment: @Phil I tried your solution, i changed the working directory to the one i chose, the problem is that if I try to download a library, it will always store it in the original OneDrive folder. I would like to have everything moved to the new folder, basically making rstudio "forget" the One Drive directory

Comment: How about reinstalling R and RStudio to the desired folder? Is this an option?