# How to change the default working directory in RStudio

Tags: r, directory, rstudio

I am trying to change the default working directory in RStudio (Version 1.4.1103) in mac ("Wax Begonia" (458706c3, 2021-01-06) for macOS).  And I followed the instruction here ([How do you change the default directory in RStudio (or R)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432344/how-do-you-change-the-default-directory-in-rstudio-or-r)).   After I change the directory under Tools | Global Options, however, the working directory stay the same even though I restarted RStudio.  Is there anything else I could try.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the tips in [`?Startup`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html)?

Comment: Not yet, thank you for the info, I will give it a try

Comment: Nope, can't get it work.   Thank you though.

Comment: Are you "active" in a project? I believe the RStudio methods for setting the default working directory are reserved for when you are not in a project.

Comment: I don't think so.    Right now I just manually set the working directory through setwd(), might be able to figure it out later.